# Customize Community Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the graph generated by the code below. How can I customize the communities the code generates where each community contains only nodes with the same color; that is, the 4 red nodes would be one community containing just the 4 red nodes, another community would be one community containing just the green nodes, and finally another community would be one containing just the orange nodes.

Also, the code needs to create the number communities equal to the number of node colors in the basic graph. Thoughts and suggestions most appreciated ... prg

```
edges = {NS <-> N1, NS <-> N11, NS <-> N18, NS <-> N24, NS <-> N27, 
  NS <-> N35, NS <-> N37, N1 <-> N4, N1 <-> N5, N1 <-> N6, N1 <-> N7, 
  N1 <-> N8, N1 <-> N9, N2 <-> N5, N3 <-> N5, N3 <-> N15, N4 <-> N2, 
  N4 <-> N3, N4 <-> N5, N4 <-> N12, N4 <-> N13, N4 <-> N14, 
  N5 <-> N15, N5 <-> N16, N5 <-> N19, N6 <-> N15, N7 <-> N10, 
  N8 <-> N16, N9 <-> N10, N10 <-> N5, N10 <-> N6, N10 <-> N8, 
  N11 <-> N6, N11 <-> N8, N11 <-> N21, N12 <-> N17, N12 <-> N40, 
  N13 <-> N6, N13 <-> N21, N14 <-> NG, N15 <-> N30, N16 <-> N6, 
  N17 <-> NG, N18 <-> N15, N19 <-> N20, N20 <-> N21, N20 <-> N30, 
  N21 <-> N22, N22 <-> N23, N22 <-> N43, N23 <-> NG, N24 <-> NG, 
  N25 <-> NG, N26 <-> N29, N26 <-> N40, N27 <-> N28, N27 <-> N40, 
  N28 <-> NG, N29 <-> NG, N30 <-> N31, N30 <-> N32, N30 <-> N33, 
  N30 <-> N34, N31 <-> N36, N32 <-> N36, N33 <-> N36, N34 <-> N31, 
  N35 <-> N34, N36 <-> N12, N36 <-> N39, N37 <-> N36, N38 <-> N40, 
  N38 <-> N43, N39 <-> N40, N40 <-> N41, N41 <-> N42, N42 <-> NG, 
  N43 <-> N25, N43 <-> N26, N36 <-> N38}

g = Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
  VertexSize -> 0.7, 
  VertexStyle -> {NS | N1 | NS | N11 | NS | N18 | NS | N24 | NS | 
      N27 | NS | N35 | NS | N37 | N1 | N4 | N1 | N5 | N1 | N6 | N1 | 
      N7 | N1 | N8 | N1 | N9 | N2 | N5 | N3 | N5 | N3 | N15 | N4 | 
      N2 -> Red, 
    N4 | N3 | N4 | N5 | N4 | N12 | N4 | N13 | N4 | N14 | N5 | N15 | 
      N5 | N16 | N5 | N19 | N6 | N15 | N7 | N10 | N8 | N16 | N9 | 
      N10 | N10 | N5 | N10 | N6 | N10 | N8 | N11 | N6 | N11 | N8 | 
      N11 | N21 | N12 | N17 | N12 | N40 | N13 | N6 | N13 | N21 | N14 |
       NG | N15 | N30 | N16 | N6 | N17 | NG | N18 | N15 | N19 | N20 | 
      N20 | N21 | N20 | N30 | N21 | N22 | N22 | N23 | N22 | N43 | 
      N23 | NG | N24 | NG | N25 | NG | N26 | N29 | N26 | N40 -> Green,
     N28 | NG | N29 | NG | N30 | N31 | N30 | N32 | N30 | N33 | N30 | 
      N34 | N31 | N36 | N32 | N36 | N33 | N36 | N34 | N31 | N35 | 
      N34 | N36 | N12 | N36 | N39 | N37 | N36 | N38 | N40 | N38 | 
      N43 | N39 | N40 | N40 | N41 | N41 | N42 | N42 | NG | N43 | N25 |
       N43 | N26 | N36 | N38 -> Lighter[Lighter[Orange]]}]

cg = CommunityGraphPlot[g, 
  VertexStyle -> PropertyValue[g, VertexStyle]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
communities = GatherBy[VertexList[g], PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexStyle] &];

CommunityGraphPlot[g, communities, VertexStyle -> PropertyValue[g, VertexStyle]]
```

[image]

Add the option

```
Method -> "Hierarchical"
```

to get

[image]

Comment: kglr: Many thanks for your creative help; much appreciated ... prg